# Edit selected value from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

This always selected the last record from my database.

This is my select tag:

```
 <select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search"  />
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php 
        $t_cost=$this->db->query("select * from t_proyek ");

        foreach($t_cost->result() as $value){
          $selected= '';
          if($t_proyek_kd_proyek == $value->nm_proyek){
            $selected = 'selected';
          }

        ?>
          <option  value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>"  echo ' selected="selected"'; >
            <?php echo $value->nm_proyek; ?>
          </option>
       <?php }?>

      </select>
```

And this is my controller:

```
$row = $this->T_cost_model->get_by_id($id);

    if ($row) {
        $data = array(
            'button' => 'Update',
            'action' => site_url('konsultan/cost/update_action'),
    'kd_cost' => set_value('kd_cost', $row->kd_cost),
    'investasi_awal' =>rupiah(set_value ('investasi_awal', $row->investasi_awal)),
    'b_operasional' => rupiah(set_value('b_operasional', $row->b_operasional)),
    'g_cost' => rupiah(set_value('g_cost', $row->g_cost)),
    'disbenfit' => rupiah(set_value('disbenfit', $row->disbenfit)),
    'pwc' => set_value('pwc', $row->pwc),
    't_proyek_kd_proyek' => set_value('t_proyek_kd_proyek', $row->t_proyek_kd_proyek),
    );
        $this->load->view('konsultan/t_cost_form', $data);
```

Comment: Hi! Can you show us the code that sets the $row variable in the second code block?

Comment: Just having a quick look here, the problem may be that you are saying selected = selected or selected = '' (blank). This is the wrong syntax. If you want a certain value to be selected you need only have the word selected, like <option name="name" value="value" selected>Value</option>. Also you are not making use of your $selected variable, and your echo 'selected="selected"'; statement is not within php tags.

Comment: FrankT what do you mean dud ??? sory im just beginer here

Callum. can u tell me how to do that

Comment: can you print $t_proyek_kd_proyek before foreach and update value here

Comment: may be this cause i have used 2 difference table ???

Comment: There is no question here

Answer (score 0):

change your `<select>` html code value like this

```
  <select name="t_proyek_kd_proyek" id="t_proyek_kd_proyek" class="select-search"  />
        <option value=""></option>    
    foreach($t_cost->result() as $value){
              $selected= '';
              if($t_proyek_kd_proyek == $value->nm_proyek){
                $selected = ' selected="selected" ';
              }

            ?>
              <option  value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>"  <?=  $selected?> >
                <?php echo $value->nm_proyek; ?>
              </option>
           <?php }?>

          </select>
```

hope it will help

Comment: Introducing short tags here is a bad idea.

Comment: this is not a short tag this is expression it will support all php web servers.

Comment: naisa@ i'm not understand

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, your last `option` tag has `selected="selected"` explicitly set:

```
option  value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>"  <?php echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>
```

Wrap that in a condition and the selected option from your loop should work.

```
option  value="<?php echo $value->kd_proyek; ?>"  <?php if ($selected) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>
```

Comment: Look at the HTML this is producing and see whether none, some or all the `option` tags have a `selected` attribute?

Comment: i'm just want show option from database where the tables is difference

Comment: You need to look at what you're currently getting as output in order to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: output alwasy getting the last record from database

Comment: I'm asking for you to look at (and hopefully present to us) the HTML output. The *actual* HTML, not an observation like "always getting the last record". What I suspect you'll see is more than one `option` has the attribute `selected`.

Comment: thanks sir for you time,
i think this just cause i haved select record from 2 deference table,,,,